# How can I stop the "Photos" Live Tile from showing deleted pictures?

Tags: windows-8, live-tiles, windows-8-photos-app

My Photos tile was showing several photos that I took to test my webcam. I deleted them, but the pictures are still showing up on my live tile (even after restarting my computer). How can I prevent them from showing up on the live tile?

Comment: This has potential to be _very_ embarrassing depending on your... Internet habits.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you go to:

```
 %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.windowsphoto_[random characters]\LocalState\
```

you'll find cached copies LargeTile?.jpg and SmallTile?.jpg

Delete the images you don't want (or replace them with ones you do want) then go to the start screen, turn off the live tile then turn it back on again.
Hope that helps.

Credits: [Technet Answers](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/w8itprogeneral/thread/39c504d2-2676-4ace-9ff7-23a3d7c53f84)

Sounds like an inconvenient answer but that's all I got :(

Comment: Didn't work out for me, but searching for "*.jpg" files in the folders inside `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Packages` helped me out: the tiles were stored inside the folder  `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Packages\FileManager_[random_characters]\LocalState`.

Answer (score 7):

Deleting the "tile" jpgs didn't work!  The images must be held in some database somewhere.

The way I found to clear the tile of deleted pictures is as follows:

1. In the Start screen swipe the mouse cursor/track pad in from the right (or move it to the bottom right corner) to display the "Charms menu".  (Note this MUST be done on the "menu" Start screen, as the Charms menu of the desktop brings up different settings options).
2. Click Settings (the "Cog" icon)
3. Click "Tiles"
4. Click the "Clear" button (under "Clear personal data from my tiles").

I suppose if you use the live tiles thing, this may not be the way to solve the problem as it presumably clears all the data for the other tiles as well.  But on the other hand, if you haven't deleted associated files for those apps, then the data would soon be repopulated?

Answer (score 2):

Easy way to do this is just delete the app.
Go to the store app and reinstall it.
It cleared my old profile picture. Remember first to delete the pictures from Facebook first or wherever its being fetched from or the pictures will be re fetched from the source.

Comment: sounds like an extreme way to accomplish, what _should_ be a settings change somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

I used the following method of updating the live tile of Photo application:

Start the app, and go to your Pictures library. The app rescans the library and removes the deleted photos from its live tile cache.

This should work for other photo sources.

Answer (score 0):

On the surface tablets, go into the photo app itself and open the charms menu and hit the gear cog settings icon, options for the photo app will then be available, select the options menu. Then simply switch off the "Shuffle Photos on app tiles" toggle. Return to your live tiles and it will no longer display photos. You can alternatively re-enable the toggle and it will have cleared the cash off deleted photos, or you could deselect albums or sources you do not wish to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Desktop. Open file explorer. If libraries aren't displayed in left bar, right click in the bar and tick display libraries. Expand libraries and right click pictures, select properties. Highlight pictures and remove. Open pictures app, switch to Skydrive and back, this will refresh it. All gone. Just repeat and add pictures back to library.